What descriptive statistics to report for a paired sample when using a nonparametric test?
I have two variables, A and B, (paired sample, before-after) and I need to conduct a paired sample nonparametric test because the distribution of the difference between A and B is not normal (assumption of normality of the difference between the paired values fails). There are around 14 records. My question is: to provide the descriptive statistics in a table, should I provide the median and IQR for A and B as the we are conducting the paired sample non-parametirc test, or should I first check the distribution of each variable separately and, if they follow a normal distribution, provide the value of the means and SDs in the table?

Why not both? That way you can quickly see if the distribution is not symmetric.

"I need to conduct a paired sample non-parametric test because the distribution of the difference between A and B is not normal". Notice this normality leads to an optimal scenario, it is not a requirement per se. Given the CLT + Slutsky's theorem, asymptotically the assumptions of the t-test can still be respected in this scenario.

Note that nothing in reality is ever normally distributed, so technically you can't make sure that normality holds. What "normality checks" do is that they allow to diagnose how clear deviations from normality are. However, neither does rejecting normality by such diagnoses mean that the t-test can't be used (see comment by @Firebug), nor does not rejecting normality mean that median and IQR shouldn't be reported.

Possibly relevant: What are good basic statistics to use for ordinal data?

(Just in case it rings a bell for anyone else:  I also have some vague memory that @whuber had a really insightful post about descriptive statistics, but I couldn't find whatever I might have been thinking of.)

Regarding the questions about first checking for normality, it may help you to read through these excellent CV threads: Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?, & How to choose between t-test or non-parametric test e.g. Wilcoxon in small samples.

Because your sample is paired, you should report the median and IQR of the difference between A and B.  You can also report statistics about A and B separately, but the key test statistic will be based on the difference between A and B in a paired test.
Note, in some audiences it can cause confusion to report A and B separately in a paired test because Median(A-B) is not equal to Median(A) - Median(B) for non-symmetric distributions.  For that reason, I would also report the mean if I was reporting A and B separately, even if my test statistic is not based on the mean.

It totally depends upon the data characteristics and a bit on your preference.
The median and IQR are rather robust measures to describe the distribution. If the distribution of your random variable A or B is strongly skewed or leptokurtic (high kurtosis), then the mean and particularly the standard deviation may not be a good idea.
So I would suggest the following: 1) plot the distribution of your data using a histogram, 2) report in the table some descriptive statistics (e.g., median/mean, SD, IQR, but maybe also min/max if there are strong outliers). 3) Given this, you can then conduct your preferred paired-sample test to compare the distributions.

It all depends on which "non-parametric" test you ran, and on the specific nature of the problem you are tackling, and what your audience may be interested in.
If you are running a Sign test, you should report the median of the paired differences, since this is what your test checks. Beyond that, you can report, or not, any other descriptive stats which may be of interest to the problem, or the audience. You could report the IQR of the paired differences (even though the Sign test tells you nothing about it!), or the mean and sd of the paired differences (which the Sign test does not test, but they remain "descriptive stats", etc.)
It gets trickier to report descriptive stats for the 2 paired samples, because your test does not really depend on them; but on the other hand, they are descriptive of the "raw" data, so why not (be careful to not flod the readers with irrelevant descriptive stats, which add nothing to the "story" you are trying to tell).
If you are instesad running Mood's median test (on the paired differences), the exact same remarks as above apply.
Now, if you are running Wilcoxon's sign rank test (WSRt), it is a completely different story. The WSRt is not a test of the median, but of the pseudo-median. It becomes a test of the median (and then also a test of the means!), iff the paired differences are symmetric; since your paired differences are not normal (enough), it is quite unlikely that it still would be symmetric. And if it were to be symmetric, then the t-test would be valid (as mentioned in a comment, the CLT will converge sufficiently fast with sample sizes as low as your 14).
As the WSRt does not test the median, reporting it as a descriptive stats could be misleading. And explaining how to interpret the pseudo-median may be challenging... Some even argue that the WSRt should no longer be used, and be replaced by the Rank-Difference test.\

This question should be answered by reference to your goals.  When people ask me, 'which _____ should I use?' I always ask them what they hope to achieve in the end (cf., my answer here).  I suppose there could be many reasons to compute descriptives, but the two that stand out as most prominent to me are: 1) characterizing the study's sample, and 2) helping to understand a result.

It is standard in biomedical research to construct a Table 1.  This lists various descriptive statistics for all of the important variables for the patients in the study.  The table helps to identify any 'weirdness' in the sample.  It also helps readers see how relevant the study is for their situation.  For example, if they are interested in potential side effects in a minority population, and the study had few minority patients included (a fairly common occurrence), then their situation and the study's don't match well and that paper may not be very relevant.
If the reason you want descriptive statistics is something like this, then I would use methods that are more standard in a Table 1-type setting.  For example, I would probably report the medians and IQR's for before and after separately, which is likely to be more helpful to readers and more in line with what they expect to see.

It is important to note that just because you have a result (e.g., a p-value), you don't necessarily have any clear sense of what is going on or why that result emerged (cf., Anscombe's quartet).
In this sort of case, you want numbers that match the internal machinery of the test you used.  Different nonparametric tests work different ways, but for paired data they are likely to all use some function of the after vs before values, e.g., the differences.  To help you understand why you didn't get a significant result when you expected one (or vise versa), you should look at the numbers the test was working with (cf., here and/or here).


